# Bulk find and replace error in SharePoint 2013 Designer

Tags: 2013, error

Two part question.

1. My issue was removing the "recentchanges" from all of my wiki pages. I tried to add a div around the recent changes menu as below:

.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>
</div>
```

For my wiki library, I was able to remove it on the list page, but when I got to a detail wiki page it would persist. I've also tried:

```
<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges" visible="false"/>
```

Both of these work to an extent, but I can't find a way to remove this from all of my wiki pages (over 500 pages) without going into each one, edit in advanced mode, and save. Does anyone have any suggestions?

2. Second question, since I couldn't find a master way to turn this off, I decided to do a bulk find and replace to add my div to each of these pages in SharePoint Designer. Once complete, every page in the browser gave me this error:

> Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField' does not have a public property named '__Error'.

If I bulk remove my div(essentially reverting the code), the error remains. So I've decided to open each file, add a space, and save. Then the error is gone and the page works fine- it just needs to be touched. But this is a lot of files to go through, so if anyone has a solution to do this faster I would appreciate it. I've tried restarting the website, restarting the App Pool, touching the web.config, nothing seems to fix outside of manually going through each page and adding a simple character and re-saving. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method instead of doing this 500 times would be to create a custom master page, create a custom stylesheet with your CSS, reference the stylesheet in your master page, set the custom master page as the master page for the site and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To the first question, I'd just write a script to find and replace your code in whatever language you're most comfortable in. I'd use C# with regex.